# Overwrite global var in one line in Python?

Tags: python

I know that I can write:

```
foo = 'bar'
def update_foo():
  global foo
  foo = 'baz'
```

But do I *really* need two lines of code there? Python, alas, won't allow me to say

```
global foo = 'baz'
```

I could also mash the two lines together with the unfortunately repetitive

```
global foo; foo = 'baz'
```

Any other shortcuts? I'm on Python 2.6.5, but I'd be curious to hear responses for Python 3 as well.

Comment: What is the intent of such exercise? When using `global` you declare you intend to meddle with variable that does not belong to you (presumably s/o else made) - but why would you override it right away, even before checking what's in it? Does not seem to make practical sense...

Comment: I agree, I've always wanted to do this. I also want smarter tuple unpacking, but you can't win them all :)

Comment: @NasBanov: I almost never check what is in it before overwriting a global variable? Most of the time, this is some kind of setting like speaker sound or mouse speed, why would I need to check what the current one is before setting it to the new one the user requested? If I want to _read_ a global variable, thanks to Python's scoping, I don't even need the global keyword most of the time!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You could use my favorite alternative to `global` (a pretty idiosyncratic taste...):

```
import sys
thismodule = sys.modules[__name__]
thismodule.foo = 'bar'

def update_foo():
  thismodule.foo = 'baz'
```

Once you've made the `thismodule` reference, you don't need to use `global` in this module, because you're always working with *qualified* names rather than *bare* names (a much better idea IMHO... but maybe in MHO only, I've not been able to convince Guido to supply `thismodule` [[or some other identifier with this functionality]] back when Python 3 was gestating).

Note that the first assignment to `foo`, at global level, can be done either with this explicit syntax, *or* by assigning to barename `foo` as you do in your code (I guess it's not surprising that my preference goes to the explicit form, though, in this case, just barely).

Comment: Giving the module a 'this' keyword? For some reason that just gives me the heebiejeebies. If I were Guido, I'd make global declarations include a giant red flashing warning sign.

Answer (score 7):

It's two statements, there aren't any other forms.

Comment: ...only if you've sworn to only ever use barenames...;-).

Answer (score 7):

You could write it like this using the `globals()` dictionary:

```
def update_foo():
  globals()['foo'] = 'baz'
```

but I would just stick with the 2 lines or the separating with a `;` approach.

Comment: True, although generally messing with `globals()` (and even more so `locals()`) is not recommended.

Comment: From http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/, "Explicit is better than implicit".

Comment: @DavidZ can you expound upon why it is not recommended?

Answer (score 5):

```
def update_foo():
    globals().update(foo='baz')
```

Answer (score 2):

**If it makes you feel better to put it all on one line...**

```
global foo; foo = 'baz'
```